# How to get fixed length number from a string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to get fixed length number from var-char field.Suppose i have a string like `text1234567890fortex23466666sortes1234567890123` then i want to get which number has fixed 10 digits continuously between chars i.e `1234567890` and My data is also like `text1234567fortex23466666sortes0987654321` then output should be 0987654321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Select regexp_substr ( <text>, '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{10}([^0-9]|$)' ) from dual;
```

to extract the first occurrence of a maximal 10-digit number. You must postprocess the result to drop the enclosing non-digits. A complete solution with repeated regexp-based extraction would be:

```
Select regexp_substr (
             regexp_substr ( <text>, '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{10}([^0-9]|$)' ) 
           , '[0-9]{10}'
       )
  from dual
     ;
```

Alternatively, break down the preprocessing by cases:

```
Select case length(i.interim)
           When 10 then i.interim
           When 12 then substr(i.interim, 2, 10 )
           Else case when regexp_instr(i.interim, '[0-9]') = 1
                     Then substr ( i.interim, 1, 10 )
                     Else substr ( i.interim, 2 )
                End
       End
  From (
           Select regexp_substr ( <text>, '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{10}([^0-9]|$)' ) interim from dual
       ) i
     ;
```

In case you want to avoid multiple calls to regexp function, you need to resort to `regexp_replace`:

```
Select regexp_replace( <text>, '^(.*[^0-9])?([0-9]{10})([^0-9].*)?$', '\2' ) from dual;
```

**Note**

In 12c, `regexp_substr` has been complemented with a new parameter to return a capture group instaed of a complete match:

```
Select regexp_substr ( <text>, '(^|[^0-9])([0-9]{10})([^0-9]|$)', 1, 1, '', 2 ) from dual;
```

The last argument indicates the capture group, the intervening arguments represent start Position for the match, occurrence, and match parameter, resp.; see [the oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303) for details.

Comment: Thank you, Your first solution is working fine but instead of using REGEXP_SUBSTR two times is it posible to get same result by using single REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: In 11g2, regexp_substr can only extract the whole match. This will include any surrounding non-digits. Afaik Oracle's regex syntax does not support lookaround syntax. 12c introduced a new parameter to regexp_substr that specifies a capture group to return instead of the complete match. Alternatively, use regexp_replace (adjust the pattern to match  the complete string). I will complement my answer accordingly.

Comment: We are using oracle12c only. Can you please provide same functionality using a single REGEXP_SUBSTR in 12c